# Merge Sort Python Coding issues

Tags: python, mergesort

```
def merge(array1: list, array2: list) -> list:
    result = []

    i = j = 0
    while i < len(array1) and j < len(array2):
        if array1[i] < array2[j]:
            result.append(array1[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(array2[j])
            j += 1

    # When we run out of elements in either L or M,
    # pick up the remaining elements and put in A[p..r]
    if i < len(array1):
        result += array1[i:]
    if j < len(array2):
        result += array2[j:]

    return result


def merge_sort(array: list) -> None:
    # if hi > lo
    if len(array) > 1:
        mid = (len(array)) // 2
        l = array[:mid]
        r = array[mid:]
        merge_sort(l)
        merge_sort(r)
        array[:] = merge(l, r)
        
        print(array)
```

My questions:
First is about if I change array[:] = merge(l, r) -> array = merge(l,r) then the result will be messed up.

```
array = merge(l,r)
```

And another issue is why I cannot use code (below) directly. I have to refer to something.

```
merge_sort(array[:mid])
merge_sort(array[mid:])
array[:] = merge(array[:mid], array[mid:])
```

Comment: Using slice will only get one copy of the list, and the `merge_sort` function will only sort on the copy.

Comment: I print array which should be the orginal one and it is sorted. If as you said, the merge funciton only merge on the copy, then the original list should remain the same.

Comment: Mergesort doesn't operate in-place which is why you need the final assignment `array[:] = merge(l, r)` to overwrite the contents of the original array with the sorted copy.

Comment: So, it here [:] means that the current array which used by the reucrsion call and it is referred back to the orignal one right?

Comment: @YihongXia Your `merge_sort` is in place, because at last you copy the merged result to the original list, but `array[:mid]` will generate a copy, causing the function to sort on the copy instead of the first half of the original list.

Comment: @MechanicPig That's clear. So, for my second question, why this can not acheive, as I didn't copy part of the list. ```merge_sort(array[:mid])
merge_sort(array[mid:])
array[:] = merge(array[:mid], array[mid:])```

Comment: Sorry, I ignored the first question. The previous comments answered the second question.@Yihong Xia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, assigning the merged results directly to the `array` will only make the it point to new list. Let's do a small experiment to observe this phenomenon:

```
>>> ar = list(range(10))
>>> same_ar = ar
>>> ar = []       # make `ar` point to a new list
>>> same_ar       # not change
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> ar = same_ar
>>> ar[:] = []    # modify `ar` in place
>>> same_ar       # change
[]
```

For the second problem, you should know that on the premise of solving the first problem, your `merge_sort` function is modifying the incoming list, but each time you use slicing, you will get a copy of the list, which causes the function to sort on the copy instead of the original list. Similarly, take a small experiment as an example:

```
>>> ar = list(range(10, -1, -1))
>>> ar
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> half = ar[:5]     # a copy of first half of `ar`
>>> half
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
>>> half.sort()       # modify `half` in place
>>> half
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> ar                # not change
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```